# CustomerGroupsId always true for cart price rules

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, sales

I'm a bit new here in the forum som feel free to slap me on the fingers if I'm dumb.

I want to change the logic in the sales rules engine so it doesn't check the salesrules_customer_id table and instead just skips that filtering.

The reason for this is that the site I'm building is going to use A lot of the same cart price rules. And the less the algorithm checks for the faster the site.

I've been debugging around in:
Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel

But still I'm not able to find what I'm searching for.

Anyone got any clue how to solves this?

Answer (score 0):

I've narrowed it down to this code:

```
public function addCustomerGroupFilter($customerGroupId)
    {
        $entityInfo = $this->_getAssociatedEntityInfo('customer_group');
        if (!$this->getFlag('is_customer_group_joined')) {
            $this->setFlag('is_customer_group_joined', true);
            $this->getSelect()->join(
                ['customer_group' => $this->getTable($entityInfo['associations_table'])],
                $this->getConnection()
                    ->quoteInto('customer_group.' . $entityInfo['entity_id_field'] . ' = ?', $customerGroupId)
                . ' AND main_table.' . $entityInfo['rule_id_field'] . ' = customer_group.'
                . $entityInfo['rule_id_field'],
                []
            );
        }
        $this->setFlag('is_customer_group_joined', true);
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['customer_group' => $this->getTable($entityInfo['associations_table'])],
            $this->getConnection()
                ->quoteInto('customer_group.' . $entityInfo['entity_id_field'] . ' = ?', $customerGroupId)
            . ' AND main_table.' . $entityInfo['rule_id_field'] . ' = customer_group.'
            . $entityInfo['rule_id_field'],
            []
        );
        return $this;
    }
```

Still not sure how I'm going to modify it though.